# Read notepad text from attached flash-drive. raspberry pi text editor shows 2 or 3 strange characters

Tags: readwrite

I want to Read notepad text from from my laptop via my flash-drive when attached to my raspberry pi. The raspberry pi text editor shows 2 or 3 strange characters only. Putting the flash-drive into my Windows 10 laptop, I can read the text from my debian raspberry pi. 
I have used the GUI text editor bundled with Raspberry Pi which is Leafpad. Further research shows that the inability of Leafpad to read Windows text files has been noted by others. I have not discovered any GUI text editor on Raspberry Pi which can read Windows text files.

Comment: Which "raspberry pi text editor"?  Presuming you are using Raspbian, there are probably at least a few dozen text editors available.  Is it part of the GUI? Or do you mean `nano`?  Also, edit in the output of `file whatever.txt`, where "whatever.txt" is the actual file you are having a problem with.

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding format issue not a rpi issue.